# Passing array variable from one page to another in php and joomla

Tags: php, arrays, session, joomla

I have an array used in a foreach() loop that I am able to pass from one page to another using a link in the sender page:

```
$annoncenumber = $book[7];
<a href="index.php?annoncenumber=' . $annoncenumber . '&option=com_aicontactsafe&view=message&layout=message&pf=4&redirect_on_success=">
```

and in the receiver page:
    $annoncenumber = $_GET['annoncenumber'];

This works fine but because of the $annoncenumber in the link I can't use the joomla menu linking system to add modules to the receiver page (menus, footer). I tried to use $_SESSION instead:

```
$annoncenumber = $book[7];
$_SESSION['lginumero'] = $annoncenumber;
```

But with this method and using a SEO optimized link:

The session result is incorrect when the person clicks on the link. It only retrieves the last value of the array. So my question is either how to get the joomla modules to show with a link that uses variables OR how to use $_SESSION to correctly pass the array variable to my receiver page when the user clicks the link. Thanks.

Comment: by disabling SEO is the easiest solution

Comment: I don't really need the SEO but I do need the joomla modules to appear. That is why I tried to use joomla menu linking function. I'm sorry about the confusion

Comment: I don't understand this, why can't you use "announcenumber" what happens when you do... we use component links in modules all the time with parameters attached...

Comment: @cppl: When I use annoncenumber in the first case (link + $_GET) everything works fine. When I use the $_SESSION to be able to use joomla menu links it only displays the last value of the array

Comment: @cppl: This is within in a php file which I attach to a joomla article using php include

Comment: what mechanism do you use to include the php in the article... are you hacking the core com_content or a you using one of the custom code in content extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the joomla class JSession instead of native PHP $_SESSION, since Joomla sometimes clears the $_SESSION variable.

http://docs.joomla.org/JSession/11.1

You should never use unsanitized $_GET to retrieve the variable, since this is a great security risk. Use the Joomla JRequest::getInt('announcenumber'); instead to properly sanitize the variable.

http://docs.joomla.org/JRequest/11.1

If the PHP file you're using to catch the request is an external file outside Joomla, then you cannot use the core Joomla classes. In that case i suggest that you rewrite your extension to comply with MVC standards.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try to implement this. I must look up 'unsanitized' $_GET and MVC standards which I have never heard of. I also found that I could include in the email link the "Itemid" of a joomla menu, thus giving me the necessary modules that I was looking for